# ShadcnUI, with select, when item is clicked, i want to display some related datas

Tags: mysql, reactjs, node.js, select, shadcnui

With react, node and shadcnUi, i call a list of product by there brands with a select. On the select item, i have the model of the product.
I want to display other information like the color for example when the item is clicked. But for some reasons, it's not displaying everything...

Thanks a lot

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogDescription, DialogHeader, DialogTitle, DialogTrigger } from "./ui/dialog";
import callAPI from "@/api/callAPI";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectGroup,
  SelectItem,
  SelectLabel,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select.tsx";

function Sampling() {
  type CameraData = {
    id: number;
    brand: string;
    model: string;
    sensor: string;
    sensor_type: string;
    sensor_width_mm: number;
    sensor_heigth_mm: number;
    sensor_width_pixel: number;
    sensor_height_pixel: number;
    photosites: number;
    megapixels: number;
    fps: number;
    dynamic: number;
    bits: number;
    pixel_capaoity: number;
    cooler: number;
  };

  const [selectedCamera, setSelectedCamera] = useState<CameraData | null>(null);

  const { data: dataCameras, error: errorCameras, isLoading: isLoadingCameras } = useSWR(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL}/api/cameras/`,
    callAPI
  );

  console.log({ selectedCamera });

  if (errorCameras) return `Erreur lors du chargement : ${errorCameras.message}`;
  if (isLoadingCameras) return "chargement en cours...";

  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger className="bg-white">Calculateur de focale</DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent className="z-50">
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Calculateur d'échantillonage</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            Sélectionne une monture puis une caméra pour savoir si la configuration est adéquate.
            <div>
              <Select>
                <SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectValue placeholder="Sélectionnez votre caméra" />
                </SelectTrigger>
                <SelectContent>
                  <SelectGroup>
                    {dataCameras.map((camera: CameraData) => (
                      <React.Fragment key={camera.id}>
                        <SelectLabel>{camera.brand}</SelectLabel>
                        <SelectItem value={camera.model} onSelect={() => setSelectedCamera(camera)}>
                          {camera.model}
                        </SelectItem>
                      </React.Fragment>
                    ))}
                  </SelectGroup>
                </SelectContent>
              </Select>
            </div>
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
      </DialogContent>
      {selectedCamera && (
        <DialogContent className="z-50">
          <DialogHeader>
            <DialogTitle>Informations sur la caméra sélectionnée</DialogTitle>
            <DialogDescription>
              <div>
                <p>Marque : {selectedCamera.brand}</p>
                <p>Modèle : {selectedCamera.model}</p>
                {/* Affichez d'autres informations sur la caméra ici */}
              </div>
            </DialogDescription>
          </DialogHeader>
        </DialogContent>
      )}
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default Sampling;
```

I want to display other informations in the displayDescription
It seems console.log is not refreshing.